# How can I create a trigger in SQL Commands?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I have made a process in Oracle APEX with this PL/SQL code:

```
UPDATE RACUN SET 
  UKUPNO_RACUN = (SELECT SUM(S.IZNOS_STAVKE) 
                  FROM STAVKA_RACUNA S 
                  WHERE S.BROJ_RACUNA_STAVKE = BROJ_RACUNA);
```

But how can I create a trigger in SQL Commands for that code?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, no - you don't really want to do that. Don't store *calculated* values. Table

- `RACUN` should contain "general" information about that bill (customer ID and name, date of purchase, etc.), while
- `STAVKA_RACUNA` contains its details (what was purchased, how many pieces of that "something", its price, etc.)

When you want to create an invoice, report or whatever, you'd select it from the database by joining those two tables:

```
select r.broj_racuna, r.datum_racuna, r.ime_kupca, sum(s.iznos_stavke) suma_iznosa
from racun r join stavka_racuna s on s.broj_racuna_stavke = r.broj_racuna
```

Why not (database) trigger? Because the one you want fires `after update` on `STAVKA_RACUNA` table. But, as it is just being changed, you can't select from it because it is *mutating*. Also, it doesn't make sense just to *update* the `RACUN` table; when will you insert rows into it? Trigger can fire `after insert or update`, no problem; it can use `insert`, `update` or `merge` statements, but it'll fail for the same *mutating table* error.

Besides, what will you do with deletes? Stavka can be reversed (stornirana), so you'd have to handle that too.

Depending on database version you use (Oracle, right?), mutating table can be "fixed" using database package (10g and lower) or a compound trigger. However, once again, that's not what you should do in the first place.

Comment: I wanted to do that because processes in Oracle APEX doesn't execute automatically

Comment: Well, you can run them yourself. For example, set it to run when certain button is pressed (e.g. "Save" or "Submit"). Post that process properties; maybe you missed something.

Comment: It executes when I press button Save for the second time. That's the problem.

Comment: Run the page in debug mode and then check what's going on.

Comment: My process: Source is PL/sql code, execution: sequence:40,point: processing, run process: once per page visit... I have tried to change this, but the process executes in the same way. After I submit the report, I have to submit it again

Comment: Hi Mateja, I could meet with you briefly online to take a look. If you're interested, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/).